# Why is this giving me a segmentation fault on one system but not another?

Tags: c, dictionary, pointers, segmentation-fault, trie

I'm running a program that creates a dictionary tree by reading in words from 'words.txt', and then can search to see if certain words are in the tree. Running this program on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler works perfectly, but I get a segmentation fault when I try to run it on my own Linux system. Any ideas as to why? Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* Node structure of trie */
struct node
{
    struct node *next[27]; // 26 for a-z and last one(26th index) is for apostrophe
    int end; // value as 1 denotes the end of the word.
};

/* This method is for creating a new node */
struct node *createNode()
{
    struct node *newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->end = 0; // set end as false i.e. 0
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) // set all children as NULL
        newNode->next[i] = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

/* This method is for inserting a word in the trie */
void insert(struct node *root, char *word)
{
    struct node *curr = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) // iterating character by character
    {
        int index;
        if (word[i] == '\'') // if character is apostrophe index is 26
            index = 26;
        else
            index = tolower(word[i]) - 'a'; // else the index as the alphabet sequence number starting from 0.
// for a - 0, b - 1, ..... z - 25
        if (!curr->next[index])
            curr->next[index] = createNode(); // create node of that character if not created yet
        curr = curr->next[index]; // then go for next character
    }
    curr->end = 1; // mark end as 1 to denote the ending of the word
}

/* This method is for searching a word in the trie */
int search(struct node *root, char *word)
{
    struct node *curr = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) // iterating character by character
    {
/* Getting index same as insert function */
        int index;
        if (word[i] == '\'')
            index = 26;
        else
            index = tolower(word[i]) - 'a';
        if (!curr->next[index]) // if node of current character not found means the word doesn't exist in trie.
            return 0;
        curr = curr->next[index];
    }
    if (curr != NULL && curr->end) // if iterated all the characters and end is 1 then the word exists.
        return 1;
    else
        return 0; // otherwise doesn't exist.
}

int main()
{
/* Reading the file line by line */
    FILE *file;
    size_t len = 1000;
    char *word = (char *)malloc(len);
    file = fopen("word.txt", "r");
    struct node *root = createNode();
    while (fgets(word, len, file) != NULL) // iterating line by line
    {
        int len = strlen(word);
        if (word[len - 1] == '\n') // removing the newline which is at the end of the every line
            word[len - 1] = '\0';
        insert(root, word); // inserting every word
    }
    int ans;
    word = (char *)("error's"); // checking the existence of the word "error's"
    ans = search(root, word);
    if (ans == 1)
        printf("\"%s\" found!\n", word);
    else
        printf("\"%s\" not found!\n", word);
    word = (char *)("hilli");// checking the existence of the word "hilli"
    ans = search(root, word);
    if (ans == 1)
        printf("\"%s\" found!\n", word);
    else
        printf("\"%s\" not found!\n", word);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this for the CS50 course?  The use a trie with 27 elements (26 letters plus one for anything else), so it seems plausible, even if you aren't use the `<cs50.h>` header.

Comment: You probably have undefined behavior. It's not guaranteed to cause an error.

Comment: You have a memory leak. You never `free(word)`. You need to do that before you reassign it with `word = (char *)("error's");`

Comment: @Barmar adding that before that line still produces a segmentation fault.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the segmentation fault.

Comment: `tolower(word[i])` is UB if `word[i]` is not  A-Z,a-z.  Perhaps `'\r'`?  Code should test  that `index` is in range before `next[index]`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica — you can call `tolower()` with any character and if it is upper-case alphabetic, it will be converted to lower case; otherwise, it will be unchanged.  However, the use of `index = tolower(word[i]) - 'a';` without verifying  that either `word[i]` is a letter or that the result is in the range 0..25 is a pkausible source of trouble in general (though not for the word "`error's`").

Comment: Could you be running into problems with CRLF endings being mapped to just newline on a Windows system and the CR not being mapped (or zapped) on the Linux system?  Try replacing `int len = strlen(word);
        if (word[len - 1] == '\n') 
            word[len - 1] = '\0';` with `word[strcspn(word, "\r\n")] = '\0';` and see whether that stops your crash.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler replaced those 3 lines with the other, and sadly still get the segmentation fault

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True, my comment should have been "tolower(word[i]) leads UB if word[i] is not A-Z,a-z by forming an out of range index for `next[index]`.

Comment: Which line in the code is causing the segmentation fault?  You'll need to use the debugger to find out, probably.  Which ought to be your first port of call in any case.  I've compiled the code with surprisingly few modifications (`static` before functions other than `main()`, `int main(void)`, and change the loops from `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)` to `int length = strlen(word); for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)` — mainly because my default compilation options require those, or roughly equivalent, changes).  It works on various rudimentary lists of words — on macOS 10.15.2 Catalina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's code that should work.  It does work on macOS 10.15.2 Catalina using GCC 9.2.0 and XCode 11.3.1 with the compiler set fussy and a number of memory debugging options enabled.  It does not attempt to free the trie that it builds; it should (it is a good exercise to be able to free the structures you build).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* Node structure of trie */
struct node
{
    struct node *next[27]; // 26 for a-z and last one(26th index) is for apostrophe
    int end; // value as 1 denotes the end of the word.
};

/* This method is for creating a new node */
static struct node *createNode(void)
{
    struct node *newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->end = 0; // set end as false i.e. 0
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) // set all children as NULL
        newNode->next[i] = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

/* This method is for inserting a word in the trie */
static void insert(struct node *root, char *word)
{
    struct node *curr = root;
    int length = strlen(word);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) // iterating character by character
    {
        int index;
        if (word[i] == '\'') // if character is apostrophe index is 26
            index = 26;
        else
            index = tolower(word[i]) - 'a'; // else the index as the alphabet sequence number starting from 0.
// for a - 0, b - 1, ..... z - 25
        if (!curr->next[index])
            curr->next[index] = createNode(); // create node of that character if not created yet
        curr = curr->next[index]; // then go for next character
    }
    curr->end = 1; // mark end as 1 to denote the ending of the word
}

/* This method is for searching a word in the trie */
static int search(struct node *root, char *word)
{
    struct node *curr = root;
    int length = strlen(word);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) // iterating character by character
    {
/* Getting index same as insert function */
        int index;
        if (word[i] == '\'')
            index = 26;
        else
            index = tolower(word[i]) - 'a';
        if (!curr->next[index]) // if node of current character not found means the word doesn't exist in trie.
            return 0;
        curr = curr->next[index];
    }
    if (curr != NULL && curr->end) // if iterated all the characters and end is 1 then the word exists.
        return 1;
    else
        return 0; // otherwise doesn't exist.
}

int main(void)
{
/* Reading the file line by line */
    FILE *file;
    size_t len = 1000;
    char *word = (char *)malloc(len);
    const char filename[] = "word.txt";
    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file '%s' for reading\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    struct node *root = createNode();
    while (fgets(word, len, file) != NULL) // iterating line by line
    {
        //int len = strlen(word);
        //if (word[len - 1] == '\n') // removing the newline which is at the end of the every line
        //    word[len - 1] = '\0';
        word[strcspn(word, "\r\n")] = '\0';
        printf("Word: [%s]\n", word);
        insert(root, word); // inserting every word
    }
    int ans;
    word = (char *)("error's"); // checking the existence of the word "error's"
    ans = search(root, word);
    if (ans == 1)
        printf("\"%s\" found!\n", word);
    else
        printf("\"%s\" not found!\n", word);
    word = (char *)("hilli");// checking the existence of the word "hilli"
    ans = search(root, word);
    if (ans == 1)
        printf("\"%s\" found!\n", word);
    else
        printf("\"%s\" not found!\n", word);
    return 0;
}
```

The code runs correctly given a data file containing a suitable subset of these lines:

```
enough
abracadabra
acid
test
hilli
error's
tests
testing
tested
tester
testosterone
acidly
acidic
```

It was tested with both DOS (CRLF) and Unix (NL or LF) line endings and was safe with both because it uses `strcspn()` to zap either sort of line ending:

```
word[strcspn(word, "\r\n")] = '\0';
```

If you had old Mac-style line endings (CR only), then you'd have problems with `fgets()` not recognizing the ends of lines — but if you fixed that (using POSIX [`getdelim()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) for example), it would work correctly with such lines too.

The changes made to your code are basically cosmetic, but allow the code to compile cleanly (source `trie79.c`; program `trie79`) using fairly stringent options:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     trie79.c -o trie79 
$
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Much appreciated!